# Do the 3 Mitzvos of entering Israel apply to the Second Temple?

Tags: halacha-theory, purim, beis-hamikdash, malchut-royalty, amalek

> וכן היה רבי יהודה אומר ג' מצות נצטוו ישראל בכניסתן לארץ:
>   להעמיד להם מלך ולהכרית זרעו של עמלק ולבנות להם בית הבחירה ([Sanhedrin 20b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.20b.8?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi))
>
> Rabbi Yehuda says: Three mitzvot were commanded to the Jewish people upon their entrance into Eretz Yisrael: to establish a king for themselves, and to cut off the seed of Amalek in war, and to build the Chosen House.

Rambam also brings it at the beginning of Melachim (1.1).

Does this rule apply to return to the Promised Land and re-building of the Second Temple?

If yes, who would be the king and would the killing of Haman constitute cutting off the seed of Amolek?